# Stack Overflow on my particular installation of Internet Explorer 9 is totally screwed

Tags: support, stack-overflow

With Internet Explorer 9 only on this machine, Stack Overflow screws up, no styles get loaded, and several JavaScript errors occur:

The first one is this:

```
SCRIPT1014: Invalid character 
stub.js?v=4f57d1d4ad7d, line 1 character 1
```

Where this `stub.js` file looks like it has some wrong format:

```
??\???F??W0qf?Bhf??^???9?s??d??w???~-h
?yD??~????!i???e3?tWW׻?K?O????"...
```

Then the next one is this:

```
SCRIPT5009: 'StackExchange' is undefined
```

On other machines there's no problem with Internet Explorer 9 and Stack Overflow, I don't know what custom settings could make this out, I don't think I have some special addons installed. It only occurs on Stack Overflow.

What could this be?

Answer (score 7):

This looks like a totally broken browser cache. Press F12, and then Ctrl-R in the window that pops up to clear the cache and see if that helps.

Comment: I'm somehow lucky this doesn't work, as I'd have to blame myself for not having thought about this.. Its really strange, as everything else works, it must be some special setting having to do with some file header things.. I don't know... Maybe reinstall will do..